# When using IOCP, should I set WSAOVERLAPPED's hEvent to NULL or to a valid handle to a WSAEVENT object?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, iocp

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **hEvent**: If an overlapped I/O operation is issued without an I/O
>   completion routine (the operation's lpCompletionRoutine parameter is
>   set to null), then this parameter should either contain a valid handle
>   to a WSAEVENT object or be null.

As I'm using IOCP, when I call WSASend() or WSARecv() I pass NULL to their last parameter (i.e., lpCompletionRoutine):

```
WSASend(pIoRequest->GetSocket(), pIoRequest->GetWsaBuffer(), 1, NULL, pIoRequest->GetFlags(), pIoRequest, NULL);

WSARecv(pIoRequest->GetSocket(), pIoRequest->GetWsaBuffer(), 1, NULL, &(pIoRequest->GetFlags()), pIoRequest, NULL);
```

My "per I/O data" class (pIoRequest) looks something like:

```
class IoRequest : public WSAOVERLAPPED
{
public:
    IoRequest()
    {
        ...
        SecureZeroMemory(this, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
        hEvent = WSACreateEvent(); // A
    }
    ...
    void ResetForNextIoRequest()
    {
        WSACloseEvent(hEvent); // B
        SecureZeroMemory(this, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
        hEvent = WSACreateEvent(); // C
        ...
    }
    ...
    DWORD& GetFlags() { return m_dwFlags; }
    ...
private:
    ...
    DWORD m_dwFlags;
    ...
};
```

It doesn’t seem to make any difference to my program’s behaviour even if I comment out the lines marked A, B and C above.

So how do you decide when to call WSACreateEvent() or simply set hEvent to NULL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using IOCP, you don't need to pass event objects, because you'll be receiving completion notifications using [GetQueuedCompletionStatus()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=D98fUP7pBM7usgaEh4DACw&usg=AFQjCNErbATkgyQ8c9lR6R1xP9aJ5ILC_A). This will work assuming you have associated the socket with the completion port using [CreateIoCompletionPort()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=Jd8fUPzUC5DGswbS74DABQ&usg=AFQjCNH6ZDgyBW-xDT03e8b_ZrBCWFYsSg).

Yes, I/O on Windows is confusing. In particular, there are at least *six* different ways to use sockets. First the two you seem to have come across:

- Overlapped I/O using IOCP (CreateIoCompletionPort, GetQueuedCompletionStatus, WSASend etc.).
  This is probably the most efficient method. You can easily integrate into the event loop any kind of event which also use IOCP. For other events, you may be able to workaround using [PostQueuedCompletionStatus](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=yuEfUNv7LJDGtAal8oGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNGkmZArw8fkNyHEPculPwmwp9SqsA). This is (AFAIK) the only method which scales for large numbers of sockets.
- Overlapped I/O without IOCP, that is using WSASend and friends with event objects, monitoring the events using e.g. [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and obtaining results using [WSAGetOverlappedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is relatively easy to integrate with any non-socket I/O which can also be mapped to HANDLE objects. However, WaitForMultipleObjects it is limited to monitoring no more than 64 handles at a time.

And also at least four more:

- Blocking calls (send, recv, and also the WSA* versions). If you do this, you're forced to use threads. This is both hard to implement correctly and likely inefficient.
- Non-blocking sockets using [select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This has the benefit that you can use similar code as on unix-like systems. However, it (AFAIK) cannot be integrated with I/O other than sockets.
- Non-blocking using [WSAEventSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is similar to the select() method, except that instead of using select() to get notifications, you map socket events to event objects, and monitor those using e.g. [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=nOcfUILmNI_Msga0r4DQBg&usg=AFQjCNGyd6R4B2v0cZSgPn0RBEoHjOy0zg). It is also similar to the overlapped without IOCP method, and suffers from the same limit of no more than 64 objects.
- Non-blocking using [WSAAsyncSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This delivers socket notifications as messages to a window within a program using using the [Windows message loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). This is easy to integrate into an application already using the message loop, such as many GUI applications.

Correct me if I left something out or if some of this doesn't actually work :).

Comment: Ambroz-Thanks for clarifying.  May I ask one more question?  Does it make sense to have "DWORD m_dwFlags" in "IoRequest" (see edited code above)?  Can I instead create a stack based DWRD dwFlags in my worker thread and pass it to WSASend() and WSARecv()?

Comment: It seems that you can have it on the stack and let it go out of scope as the operation is in progress. From WSARecv page: "In this case, lpNumberOfBytesRecvd and lpFlags are not updated". WSASend does not have this issue, as it just takes a value and not a pointer.